# Заполнение графа соответствующими вершинами

Tags: python, python-3.x, графы

Знакомлюсь с питоном

Есть граф :

```
G = {1: [2, 4], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [6], 5: [6]}
```

Мне нужно заполнить все смежные вершины примерно так:

```
G = {1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3, 4, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [1, 2, 6], 5: [2, 6], 6: [4, 5]}
```

Хотел использовать цикл типа :

```
for i in G:
     for j in G[i]:
         if j in G[i]:
             if j!=i:
                G[i].append(j)
```

...но тогда, к примеру, вершина `6:[...]` не отобразится в массиве. Подскажите, кому не сложно .

Comment: `if j in G[i]:` но это всегда будет `True`, ведь строчкой выше `j` и перебирается циклом по `G[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За 2 прохода по исходному словарю.
Первый проход - создание обратного словаря (значение: список_ключей).
Второй проход - объединение двух словарей.

```
from collections import defaultdict

G = {1: [2, 4], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [6], 5: [6]}
P = defaultdict(list)

for k,l in G.items():
    for v in l:
        P[v].append(k)

for k,v in G.items():
    P[k].extend(v)

print(P)
```

```
defaultdict(list,
            {1: [2, 4],
             2: [1, 3, 4, 5],
             3: [2, 4],
             4: [1, 2, 3, 6],
             5: [2, 6],
             6: [4, 5]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если граф неориентированный + все рёбра описаны лишь единожды, то можно сделать так:

1. Пройти по всем ключам исходного словаря, перед этим создав новый словарь `H`, состоящий из ключей исходного графа. Изначальные значения для каждого ключа — пустые списки;
2. Пройти по всем значениям списка для текущего ключа и сделать следующее: пусть ключ равен `key` и текущее значение равно `value`, тогда мы **добавим в список для ключа `key` значение `value` и добавим в список для ключа `value` значение `key`**. Поскольку, как было написано выше, граф неориентированный, то пару (ключ-значение) можно перевернуть, т.е. представить значение в виде ключа, а ключ — в виде значения.

```py
G = {1: [2, 4], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [6], 5: [6]}
H = dict()
for i in range(1, 6 + 1): # вместо 6 можно поставить кол-во вершин графа
    H[i] = []

for i in G:
    for elem in G[i]:
        if i < elem: # чтобы алгоритм добавлял в словарь пары,      
                     # в которых ключ исходного словаря < эл-та списка
            H[i].append(elem)
            H[elem].append(i)

print(H)
# {1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3, 4, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [1, 2, 3, 6], 5: [2, 6], 6: [4, 5]}
```

Comment: Что-то в роде такого ? :

` for i in G:`
    ` if G[i] not in g:`
        ` g.setdefault(i,[])`

Был бы благодарен за небольшой код

Comment: @Zvukoed можно проще: `for i in G: H[i] = []` — так можно быстро создать словарь для каждой вершины исходного графа